# flatten array for Flatlist, React Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

so I'm working on an app in which I receive an array from `getDerivedStateFromProps`, and with that set the state of `list`, this is an example of the array:

```
const data = [
  [
    {
      "exerciseName": {
        "exerciseName": "Barbell Bench Press",
      },
      "key": 0.4867576438357962,
      "numOfSets": 1,
      "paddingBottom": 30,
      "reps": "",
      "reps2": "",
      "reps3": "",
      "reps4": "",
      "sets": "",
      "sets2": "",
      "sets3": "",
      "sets4": "",
      "weigth": "",
      "weigth2": "",
      "weigth3": "",
      "weigth4": "",
    },
  ],
]
```

as you can see is a nested array and that's probably why it doesn't let me display it in the Flatlist. This is the function I use to get the list:

```
class mondayExercises extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      list: [],

    };  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (props?.list) {
      const mergedArray = [].concat.apply([], props.list);
      const flatten = mergedArray.flat(1);
      return {
         list: [...state.list, flatten],
      };
    }
    return null;
  }
```

I already managed to merge the arrays together, but is there a way to flatten it without changing the entire code of the app?

Comment: `[].concat.apply` is not needed if you're using spread syntax. Also you can use `.flat()` to flatten an array.

Comment: I've tried use `.flat()` but it doesn't do anything, I'm not sure why, I edited the code so you can see where I used it.

Comment: it does do something?

Comment: I edited the code above

Comment: You also need to spread the `flatten` array in your return value. `[...state.list, ...flatten]`

Comment: Using `flat` will remove the nested array. What are you expecting?

Comment: You are a genius my friend, thank you so much, It worked perfectly